# Practical uses for the option to pass `Supplier` as a message supplier in JUnit 5

Tags: junit, message, junit5, junit-jupiter, supplier

The [`Assertions`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html) class in JUnit 5 allows for passing an [`Supplier<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) as a `messageSupplier`, an object that provides the text of a message to report when the test fails.

For example, [`assertEquals`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals(char,char,java.util.function.Supplier)):

```java
public static void assertEquals​( char expected,
                                 char actual,
                                 Supplier<String> messageSupplier )
```

I am wondering what the **practical use of such a supplier** might be, specifically in the context of unit testing.

I can imagine perhaps localizing the strings, though that seems a bit strange to localize when the audience is the members of a development project.

➥ Are there any other practical uses of passing such a message supplier rather than [hard-coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) message string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## When building message is expensive

If I remember correctly, we - the JUnit 5 team - introduced the supplier variant for cases in which building the message string is costly, eg due to accessing a database. You’d only want to do this if necessary, ie in case of failure.

Answer (score 8):

## When the message can be built only in case of failure

Besides being useful when building the message is expensive, as already answered, I think another interesting and useful use-case is when the failure message can be constructed **only in case of failure**.

For example, let's say that you have an object as a result of one of your methods, and you expect that object to be `null`. In case of failure you want to show a failure message with some information taken from the unexpected non-null object, e.g., by calling one of its methods:

```java
MyEntity e = mySut.find(...);
assertNull(e, "Unexpected found entity with id: " + e.getId());
```

This test method will always throw a `NullPointerException` when the test should succeed. In fact, the message string is **always** evaluated, being an argument of the assert method.
Instead of resorting to a more complex and involved solution, undermining the readability of your tests, like

```java
MyEntity e = mySut.find(...);
String failureMessage = "";
if (e != null)
   failureMessage = "Unexpected found entity with id: " + e.getId();
assertNull(e, failureMessage);
```

You can simply use the assert method with a message supplier:

```java
MyEntity e = mySut.find(...);
assertNull(e, () -> "Unexpected found entity with id: " + e.getId());
```

Now, the body of the lambda will be executed only in case of failure, when the object used to create the message is surely not `null`.